# sql with case when selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing this question,

> Write a SQL query to rank scores. If there is a tie between two
>   scores, both should have the same ranking. Note that after a tie, the
>   next ranking number should be the next consecutive integer value. In
>   other words, there should be no "holes" between ranks.

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
+----+-------+
```

> For example, given the above Scores table, your query should generate
>   the following report (order by highest score):

```
+-------+------+
| Score | Rank |
+-------+------+
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 3.85  | 2    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.50  | 4    |
+-------+------+
```

the answer is:

> Write your MySQL query statement below

```
SELECT Score,   
  CASE
        WHEN @prev = Score THEN @rank
        WHEN @prev := Score THEN @rank := @rank + 1
        WHEN @rank := @rank + 1 THEN @rank
  END AS Rank
FROM Scores, (SELECT @rank := 0, @prev := NULL) r
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

I don't understand this section:

```
WHEN @rank := @rank + 1 THEN @rank
```

Why do I need then, when this line can be triggers?

Comment: "when this line can be triggers?" - erm, what? Also, is it oracle or mySQL?

Comment: If you're asking what := means, that sentence is essentially saying ' when rank equals rank + 1'. In this case the equals is not an assignment of rank to rank, it's saying when it mathematically equals (if you do C++ or different languages, think the difference between '=' and '=='. ':=' is used in psuedo code. You can google something like this by googling "colon equals operator".

Comment: This line is needed just to increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
WHEN @rank := @rank + 1 THEN @rank
```

It is incrementing `@rank` and returning the incremented variable.  It is almost entirely equivalent to:

```
ELSE @rank := @rank + 1
```

(The only difference would be `NULL` values, but presumably the value is not `NULL`.)

What is the logic?  MySQL interprets an expression as true when it is non-zero and non-NULL.  An incremented positive counter would be non-zero and non-NULL, so the `when` clause is true.  The value is then returned.